# $x^n - 1$ factors in finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields

I am having some difficulty with some Galois problems and I was wondering if it is always true that

$x^n-1$ is a factor of $x^{nm}-1$ in a finite field,

and if not what conditions need to be imposed.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that $X^n-1$ is a factor of $X^{mn}-1$ over **any** field, indeed over any ring.

Comment: Yes! It is- so sorry, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$y^m-1 = (y-1)(y^{m-1}+y^{m-2}+\cdots+y+1)$. Then take $y=x^n$.